# flutter unity AR black screen on release apk and works fine in debug

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, dart, augmented-reality

I have a flutter app that I am integrating unity AR into it using this package:

> https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget

When I was developing and debugging the debug apk works perfectly in the following video:

> https://ufile.io/p7jf2aaa

But in release signed apk the AR camera remains black and some weird things happen, like the camera is not dismissed when pressing the dismiss button, the behavior is in the following video:

> https://ufile.io/nok0qprs

This is a new issue that I am not familiar with (not a unity programmer), so if some unity/flutter expert can help with such an issue.

Answer (score 6):

So an no one has answered the question, I found the solution myself:
you must modify your pro guard unity txt to the following content:

```
-keep class bitter.jnibridge.* { *; }
-keep class com.unity3d.player.* { *; }
-keep interface com.unity3d.player.IUnityPlayerLifecycleEvents { *; }
-keep class org.fmod.* { *; }
-keep class com.google.androidgamesdk.ChoreographerCallback { *; }
-keep class com.google.androidgamesdk.SwappyDisplayManager { *; }
-ignorewarnings
-keep class com.unity3d.plugin.* { *; }
-keep class com.xraph.plugins.flutterunitywidget.UnityUtils { *; }
```